# .c_str() doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c++, c-strings

I want to create a process to read out some serial port. However the user should be able to change the path where the program is located in the future. This is why I would like to include the variable BasePathFile, which is set to the default value durin the initialization of the class:

```
const std::string BP = "C:\\aerospec_developement\\";
...
BasePathFile = BP;
...
```

Can someone explain why //1 doesn't work, but //2 is fine

```
void AerospecGUI::ReadPressure()
{
//1 const char *Args = ("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C powershell /C "+ BasePathFile+"sourcecode\\pressure.ps1 -comport COM4 -baud 1200 -parity None -data 8 -stopbits one").c_str();
//2 const char *Args = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C powershell /C C:\\aerospec_developement\\sourcecode\\pressure.ps1 -comport COM4 -baud 1200 -parity None -data 8 -stopbits one";

STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;
memset(&StartupInfo, 0, sizeof(StartupInfo));
memset(&ProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(ProcessInfo));
StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(StartupInfo);
wchar_t wargs[1000];
mbstowcs(wargs, Args, strlen(Args)+1);//Plus null
LPWSTR argsptr = wargs;

bool result = CreateProcess(NULL, argsptr, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                             &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo);
...
```

Further, the author wrote a very similar line in another function. But this one worked.

```
bool AerospecGUI::FTP(std::string command, std::string file)
{
// This function executes a batch script with the given parameters. The batch script
// generates a .ftp file which contains the commands to perform the action given by "command"
// (get, put, delete).
const char *Args = ("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C "+BasePathFile +"FTP\\FileTransfer.bat " + ServerURL + " root password " + command + " " + BasePathFile + "FTP\\ " + file +" " + BasePathFile + "FTP\\" + file.substr(0,file.size()-4)+".ftp").c_str();
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;
memset(&StartupInfo, 0, sizeof(StartupInfo));
memset(&ProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(ProcessInfo));
StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(StartupInfo);
wchar_t wargs[1000];
mbstowcs(wargs, Args, strlen(Args)+1);//Plus null
LPWSTR argsptr = wargs;
...
```

Comment: And what is `BasePathFile` ? Is it a `std::string`?

Comment: The pointer provided by `c_str()` is only valid for the lifetime of the `std::string` instance. So if you have a temparary `std::string` instance, the pointer isn't longer valid after that statement.

Comment: This is unreadable!!!

Comment: On an unrelated note, remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, so the use of the `argsptr` is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1` and the original author code are wrong: `c_str()` returns a pointer to a C-like string, but it's a member function of the `std::string` class (see [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)). Dereferencing its pointer after the `std::string` object has expired is undefined behavior (may or may not work).

`2` works fine instead

```
const char *Args = "C:\\... one";
```

since it's a string literal and its lifetime spans for the entire program execution.

Answer (score 1):

For `1` you create a *temporary* `std::string` object, and gets a pointer to its internal string. Once the temporary object is destructed the string ceases to exist and the pointer will not be pointing anywhere valid.

For `2` you have an actual constant string literal, who has a lifetime of the program and will never cease to exist.

That is seems to be working for your second example is just a fluke. What you have with the stray invalid pointer is *undefined behavior* and sometimes those might seem to work just fine.